# Problem in Crystal report 7 with special character

Tags: crystal-reports, special-characters, crystal-reports-7

We have a report designed on crystal report 7 since years ago, recently we discover a problem as in below which i wonder what is the reason behind and when it does appear if it is an old problem or just appear recently for any case.

All The report columns are read from the system data set directly except the last column which is a formula of adding values in the current row to the value in the previous cell of the same column.

The problem in case of existing special character in any text field then this formula applied taking into considerations not only the values of the current row only but also the previous row.

Please note that we didn't face this problem on the same report designed on crystal report 23 with the same data, but some of our clients not updated with the latest system upgrade.

[The correct Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWOtZ.png)

[Incorrect Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01aBo.png)

[Incorrect Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atGKS.png)

Comment: Possible to add a sample screenshot? Also if you could give examples of expected result and what the current result is.

Comment: May you show the formula?

Comment: the formula is:

Comment: numberVar bal;

if PreviousIsNull ({StatementOfAccounts.account}) or ({StatementOfAccounts.account} <> Previous ({StatementOfAccounts.account})) then
    bal := {StatementOfAccounts.Balance} 
else
    bal := bal + ({StatementOfAccounts.sign} * {StatementOfAccounts.Amount})

Comment: @AleksandarZoric screenshots added